# How do I send data from a kinect to an arduino to control a servo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am using Microsoft visual studio to receive skeleton data, send the data to an arduino, which will then move a servo motor based on how the user moves.

I have no idea what I'm doing so can someone point me towards a tutorial that teaches me about serial communication between a Kinect and an arduino? I have only found ones that use visual basic and not microsoft visual studio.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The Robotics section of StackExchange would probably be a better place to ask this.  Here is a link to "Kinect" and "Arduino" filter: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinect+arduino

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt even know that section existed. Haha

Comment: did you post a new question anywhere?